# how to use functor and function pointer together? unable to assign function to a function pointer

Tags: c++11

I am just trying out c++11. I want to demonstrate functor and function pointer in the same program but I keep getting an error.how to use functor and function pointer together? unable to assign function to a      function pointer. unable to assign the function test1 and test2 to function pointer foo
cannot assign Functortest* to a void* is the error i am getting. what should i do, why am i not able to assign the function to the function pointer foo and foo1

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 using namespace std;



 class Functortest{

 public:
     Functortest(){
         //foo=void(*)();

         //void(*foo1)(string);
     }
     void operator()(int option){
         switch (option){
         case 1: 
             void(*foo)();
             foo=test1;
             break;
         case 2:
             void(*foo1)();
             foo = test2;
         }

     };
     void test1(){

         cout << "TEST1 CALLED";
     }
     void test2(string msg){

         cout << "TEST2 CALLED msg:  "<< msg;
     }
 private:
     void *foo;
     void *foo1;
     /*void(*foo)();
     void(*foo1)(string);*/
 };

 void main(){

     Functortest funct;
     funct(1);
     funct(2);
 }
```

Comment: `test1` and `test2` are *member functions*. Pointers to those are of the type `void (Functortest::*)()`, which is incompatible to types like `void(*)()` of free and static member functions.

Comment: So how do i fix this issue ?

Comment: After trying to fix the problems and taking a more careful look at your program - I don't quite know what you're trying to do. There are two functions `test1` and `test2` and two data members `foo` and `foo1`, and something is done to both of them in `operator()`. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do in `operator()`; do you want to call through the pointer-to-member-function and assign a different function? Note the types of a pointer to `test1` and `test2` are incompatible (I missed the second one has a parameter in my first comment).

Answer (score 3):

[The parashift C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html) contains quite some information on how you can use member function pointers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
//using namespace std; // <-- better avoid `using namespace` at file scope


class Functortest {
public:
    Functortest()
        : foo(&Functortest::test1)   // better use the mem-initializer-list
        , foo1(&Functortest::test2)  // to initialize members
    {}

    void operator()(int option){
        switch (option){
        case 1: 
            (this->*foo)();
            foo = &Functortest::test1;    // after the call?
            break;
        case 2:
            (this->*foo1)("Hello World"); // need to pass an argument
            //foo = &Functortest::test2;  // <-- this won't work! (A)
            break;                        // better always end with a break
        }
    };

    void test1() {
         std::cout << "TEST1 CALLED\n";
    }
    void test2(std::string msg) {
         std::cout << "TEST2 CALLED msg: " << msg << "\n";
    }

private:
    void (Functortest::*foo)();             // declares a data member foo
    void (Functortest::*foo1)(std::string); // declares a data member foo1
};

int main() {             // NOT `void main`
    Functortest funct;
    funct(1);
    funct(2);
}
```

**On the line commented with `// <-- this won't work! (A)`:**

As you can see from the declarations of the data members `foo` and `foo1`, those two have different types:

- `foo` is of the type `void (Functortest::*)()`, i.e. `foo` is a *pointer to a member function of class `Functortest`, which takes no arguments and returns nothing*. It is the same type as a pointer to the specific member function `test1` of class `Functortest`.
- `foo1` is of the type `void (Functortest::*)(std::string)`, i.e. `foo1` is a *pointer to a member function of class `Functortest`, which has a parameter of type `std::string` and returns nothing*. It is the same type as a pointer to the specific member function `test2` of class `Functortest`.

A function that takes no arguments cannot be called with an argument (trivial), similarly, a function that has a parameter cannot be called with no arguments. Therefore, the types of `foo` and `foo1` are incompatible. For the same reason, you cannot assign a pointer to `Functortest::test1` to a *pointer to a member function [...] which takes an argument of type `std::string`*.